# How to find the difference between two text files with PHP

Tags: php, scripting

Lately, I've been wondering how to find the difference between two files with PHP. Lets say for example I have one text files that says:

```
"Line one data = test test"
```

Then one file that says:

```
"Line one data = test test Line two data = test test"
```

What I want to do is output the difference between the two files which would be:

```
"Line two data = test test"
```

How can I accomplish this with PHP? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does your PHP have the xdiff extension available to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the text files to strings then use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$one = "Line one data = test test";
$two = "Line one data = test test Line two data = test test";

$difference = str_replace($one, "", $two);
```

Or use [str_ireplace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) for case-sensitive replacing.

Comment: Clever, but it wouldn't work if the input was `"Line one data = test test"` and `"Line one data EXTRA STUFF = test test"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$str1 = "Line one data = test test";
$str2 = "Line one data = test test Line two data = test test";
```

If $str2 is the longer string and $str1 is always at the beginning of $str2 then you can use:

```
echo substr($str2, strlen($str1));
```

It is faster than str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can start of with a md5 checksum of both files. If out put hash is different then the files are different. But I'm pretty sure that's not the question in mind. Since there is no easy answer for what I think your asking. You might want to conciser reading up on 'diff'. Which is in sorts an algorithm that can read 2 files and determine not only if they are different but do essentially a side by side comparison of the 2 files showing you where the differences are. Now Im sure this is more than doable in PHP. Just not sure anyone has as of yet then again I don't search extensively for it either. Only time I use diff is when I am running through my version controlled code on svn or git.

There is a nice program called "Notepad++" it has the ability to add plugins in to it, of which a plugin for comparing like just described is available.